# Install Windows10 on older mac with boot camp does not provide install option

Tags: bootcamp, mojave, windows

I'm trying to install Windows10 on my old MBP (Model: MacBookPro10,1). I prepared a USB-Stick formatted as FAT32 with a MBR. I followed this documentation (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/bootcamp-assistant/bcmp09f5f773/6.1/mac/10.14) and Step 4 says:

> At the Select Tasks step, select all the tasks, then click Continue.

But in my case, the last task is not available. What do I need to do?

I'm running macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6 (all updates are installed) on that machine.

[image]

--

Update: diskutil list cli output

```
$>diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Mother                  499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Comment: Also what version of macOS

Comment: @SteveChambers running: macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6 (all updates are installed)

Comment: I added that to your question. That *is* strange. I have no idea, but it would be a good idea to add the output of "diskutil list" to your original question. That might help.

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks for improving the question. I also added diskutil list output.

Comment: 1) How did you manage to upgrade to Mojave without switching to APFS? 2) Do you have a fusion drive?  BootCamp does not work well with Fusion Drives (from my own experience, although that might just be my setup)

Comment: @MatthewBarclay 1) I did not upgrade. My new MBP needed a repair and in order to be able to continue working, I put the TimeMachine backup from the new one on the old one. 2) No Fusion drive

Could this be the cause of the error? What if I do an upgrade to Catalina. Or should I put a fresh new OS on it and then it might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the file system. (Thanks to @MatthewBarclay for the hint) It seems that one need to use APFS. I installed a fresh copy of OSX and then everything worked fine

Comment: Consider marking this answer as accepted to avoid it being bumped by Community user as unanswered.